# Why is sem_open returning invalid pointer in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, semaphore, errno

I have been stuck into this for quite sometime now. Have a legacy code (in C) that worked on some linux flavors. I am trying to port it on to iOS. I am running the app on iPhone 6.1 simulator

I am trying to use semaphores, by opening one as:-

```
sem_t * ptr_sem = NULL;
 
ptr_sem = sem_open("robin", O_CREAT , S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP, 0);

if (ptr_sem == SEM_FAILED) {
    printf("\nerror number:%d", errno);
 
    return -1;
} else {
    printf("\n semaphore creation errno: %d", errno);
    return 0;
}
```

This code returns 0 every time it is run. It is worth noting that for every new semaphore name, *errno* is 22 (**EINVAL**) for the first time, and for all subsequent `sem_open()` attempts (even after closing the simulator), *errno* is set to 13 (**EACCES**). Also, the return value of the pointer returned is an invalid memory address (0x000..5). I have checked some similar questions above - tried doing an `unlink()` before `open()`, but it also didn't work for me.

Can anyone let me know what is the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux flavors, the semaphore name passed to `sem_open()` is supposed to be "/somename". So, in your source code, the string "robin" is not correct. It should be "/robin". Nevertheless, the **EINVAL** return code would only appear if:

- either the initial value (4th parameter) is bigger than **SEM_VALUE_MAX**
- or the name (1st parameter) contains only "/" characters.

The problem likely comes from the 3rd parameter (access mode). You specify the creation of a semaphore (in the lower layers, this is a file creation in the file system) but the mode is set to "S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP" that is to say execute permission for the owner and read permission for the group. This is incoherent as the owner will need to read and write into the file. Internally, this triggers the creation of a file with the following parameters:

```c
fd = open (tmpfname, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IXUSR | S_IRGRP);
```

The preceding may explain why you also get **EACESS** error.